# set of points with max distance

Tags: algorithm, points

I have a set with 6000 vectors (n dim). I calculated the distance matrix to collect all the distances. Suppose I want to spot the 10 points that are more distant each other, i.d. they are the subset in which the sum of distances is the highest between every other possibilities in that set.
If I want to discriminate also with a threshold avoiding two points too close, what should be the fastest algorithm that can do that?

cheers

Daniele

Comment: Sounds NP-hard. (very similar to metric-based / norm-based clustering). If i'm right, you need to use heuristics. Examples: alternating least-squares, expectation-maximization and co. (the latter is also the one used in kmeans)

Comment: Look up "K-means clustering" or "CAST clustering", this is not a trivial problem

Comment: You might try considering only the points on the convex hull

Comment: I was thinking about also some graph, but i need a push to go to the right direction